# Python if/else loop not working

Tags: python

I have a directory where csv files are located. The code reads the files and creates histograms based on the data in the files.

However, I am trying to make it so that at the command line, I can enter one of the column headers in the csv file and the code will only make a graph of the specified command. Example: python histogram_maker.py "C:/Folder" Area.

I was able to do that, but I want to add a part that would create an error message in case the user enters a command that is not specified in the csv file. Example: Perimeter does not exist. What is wrong with my code?  Even if something exists I get "does not exist" 20 times on the command prompt, but it still makes all the files that I need.  How do I stop this repetition and make it so that the error only comes up if something is not in the csv file.

```
        for column in df:
            os.chdir(directory)
            if len(sys.argv)>2:
                for x in arguments:
                    if x.endswith(column):
                       #code for histogram
                    else: 
                        print "does not exist"
```

Answer (score 6):

You are testing *all* the arguments, even if there is only one that matches. For each argument that doesn't match, you print your error message.

Use the `any()` function to see if there are any matches:

```
if len(sys.argv)>2:
    if any(x.endswith(column) for x in arguments):
        #code for histogram
    else: 
        print "does not exist"
```

or invert the test; use `not` and bail out early:

```
if len(sys.argv)>2:
    if not any(x.endswith(column) for x in arguments):
        print "does not exist"
        sys.exit(1)

    #code for histogram
```

If `any()` with a generator expression is a little too hard to grok, you can still use a `for` loop, but you need to use `break` to end the loop early and a `else:` suite that'll be executed when the `for` loop was *not* exited early:

```
for x in arguments:
    if x.endswidth(column):
        break  # found a match
else:
    # `for` loop was not exited, so no match found
    print "does not exist"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I'd raise `ValueError` or something suitable *just in case* something else could handle it... and let that cause a system exit if needs be...

Comment: @JonClements: From context (previous question and the use of `sys.argv`) it is clear this is a command-line script.

Comment: Yup - I'd still raise an exception instead though ;)

Comment: I find for elses slightly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this....

```
    for column in df:
        os.chdir(directory)
        if len(sys.argv)>2:
            found = False
            for x in arguments:
                if x.endswith(column):
                   found = True
                   #code for histogram
                   break
            if (found == False):
                print "does not exist"
```